# How place big text in UILabel or UITextView

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have `UILabel` (in `UIScrollView`) with

```
self.testlabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.testlabel.sizeToFit()
```

and text with 26455 characters, when I set text to label :

```
self.testlabel.text = content
```

I don't see my text, but if text is much smaller than 26455 characters then all fine.

So, how to place a big text in `XCode`?

Comment: Have you tried numberOfLines = 2 or more

Comment: You should sizeToFit() function after set text to label.

Comment: yes, if it set to 0, i see text normally, but i need more rows. @igor-bidiniuc its after sizetofit()

Comment: How have you set the UILabel/TextView inside the scrollView? ScrollViews are tricky when it comes to layoutting.

Comment: @Rikh i put UILabel in ScrollView without problems, and its works fine with little text, i think about paging of information.

Comment: What are the constraints on the UILabel? Have you put a top, leading, trailing and bottom?

Comment: @Rikh of course i have all of these constraints. I think that UILabel(TextView) have limits on chars, and these elements must have pages. Like a button "More" or something like that.

Comment: `UITextxView` becomes scrollable if the text doesn't fit inside the height you specified. If you want all the content to be visible inside a `UILabel` and use the scrollView to scroll, you can do so by setting `numberOfLine` property to 0 and setting the `lineBreakMode`(i think thats what its called) to word wrap and set the height to be `>=` to a minimum height.

Comment: I would suggest you use a `UITextView` with a minimum height if all you want to do is make a scrollable label.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the label height constraint is fixed.
Try adjusting the scrollview content size depending on the text height.

Comment: No, label isnt fixed. btw, i have more elements in scrollview than 1. also, scroll is fine(i can scroll to bottom), but text is empty. (i tried set textcolor to black, i think that maybe text was white, but its not true). Text have: \r\n\r\n and \t maybe some chars break the UILabel?